# No targets shown in WEINRE (Cordova/PhoneGap)

Tags: javascript, web-applications, cordova

I've been trying to connect my device to weinre, yet I cannot see any target device in it.

This are the steps I'm following:

1. Creating project in Cordova
2. Adding android platform to the project
3. Adding the weinre script to my project's index.html
4. Initiating weinre server in my computer
5. Pinging both devices IP from each other to ensure they can see each other over the network
6. Opening weinre server in my chrome browser
7. Running my App
8. No target ever appear

Please if I'm doing something wrong tell me, but can't see, to connect any target itno my weinre server.

Best regards.

Comment: Are you sure that your app fetches the script when it starts?  It has to initiate contact with the weinre server for things to work. (I think; I've only used it with pure web applications, not Cordova.)

Comment: It should be, it's an every day script. I must say I've tried putting it inside and outside of the deviceready event.

Comment: I used to have [such problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332853/is-there-a-real-solution-to-debug-cordova-apps) but finally got it working! using weinre and cordova (no Phonegap build) and to save hassle for future devs, who may face the same problem, I made a [YouTube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEqwnpLYnI0) ;)