# Is there a real solution to debug cordova apps

Tags: android, debugging, cordova, emulation, mobile-webkit

I spent the last two days trying to figure out how to debug an HTML5 app I created using Cordova 3.2 and deployed to an Android 2.3 device. All the articles/posts I've seen provide hacks rather than real solutions :( and most of the time, none of them works for my case; debug the css styles and the Angularjs code inside my app..

So far I tested;

**debug.phonegap.com**

I injected the script to the `index.html` file then visited the generated URL in debug.phonegap.com but nothing happens; only a blank page.

**Weinre**

Most of the articles I found point to obsolete Github repository that countain a Jar file.. but it's not found :(

**Edge inspect**

It works and shows the webpage I'm browsing on the PC inside the mobile.. But the problem is that it uses some other integrated browser (or emulator) than the one that runs phonegap apps; so the results are not accurate.

**Chrome emulator**

Same as Edge inspect; it doesn't allow to view real web-kit v530 that is shipped with Android 2.3.

**The dream solution**

The perfect solution would be an extension to Google Chrome (desktop) that enables you to switch the desktop browser to the same one found in Android 2.3 platforms; no emulation no hacks, just the browser itself with web-kit v 530.

Unfortunately such solution doesn't exist :( or I'm wrong?

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Debugging in PhoneGap · phonegap/phonegap Wiki](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**NOTICE**

This answer is old (January 2014) many new debugging solutions are available since then.

---

I finally got it working! using weinre and cordova (no Phonegap build) and to save hassle for future devs, who may face the same problem, I made a [YouTube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEqwnpLYnI0&feature=youtu.be) ;)

Comment: I was missing the IP proper configuration, now it works flawlessly, thanks so much!

Comment: You can use [this](http://localtunnel.me/") to debug web/cordova projects even if the device is not connected to the same WiFi network.

Comment: Weinre isn't debugger, it allows only DOM inspections, you can't debug js and even watch console messages

Comment: Did you test GapDebug ?

Comment: It has been a long time ago since this question was asked :)  maybe in my next project I will test it.

Comment: This method seems to be deprecated, take the one from @rdchambers in case you have a new-ish phone.

Comment: Consider raising the volume on the video?

Comment: ...how is a link to a youtube video an acceptable answer?

Comment: @Meekohi he made the video :)

Comment: I'd rather have a link to a tutorial on a blog without video. I'll check it out anyway though!

Comment: As with all stackoverflow answers - a link to a solution (whether made by the author or not), is frowned upon. Keep the solutions here, and not externally where they might be gone one day.

Comment: Is there a webpage version of that tutorial? @numediaweb

Answer (score 152):

**FOR ANDROID:**

You only need to enable “USB remote debugger” within your android device and plug with a USB cable. Then open your application in the device. Chrome will detect the remote browser and you can see the console in the same way than you see it when you use Chrome locally.

Use this link: `chrome://inspect/#devices` in Chrome browser (you'll have to paste it into the nav bar).

If your app crashes in the device you only need to see the console’s log within your browser and see what happens. You also can add functionality, change variables, and override functions in the same way than we do it with our local browser.

Read [this article](http://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-android/) for more information on the steps to take.

**This will work ONLY with devices running Android 4.4+.**

**FOR iOS:**

Use Safari for iOS, follow these steps:

1.In your iOS device go to Settings > Safari > Advanced > Web Inspector to enable Web Inspector

2.Open Safari on your iOS device.

3.Connect it to your computer via USB.

4.Open Safari on your computer.

5.In Safari’s menu, go to Develop and, look for your device’s name.

6.Select the tab you want to debug.

[image]

Comment: I can see the console and my app in chrome on my computer, while my smartphone is connected via usb. Very cool solution.

Comment: It did not find my phone until I ran `adb start-server`.

Comment: @Leukipp I also face same problem but after that add ADT on my windows system startup. my problem solve..

Comment: Answer presents solution to the wrong problem -- the question is not about debugging a browser, it's about debugging a WebView. These are slightly different as evident from a multitude of frustrated users confused because their WebViews where their applications are displayed, do not show up in `chrome://inspect`.

Comment: Android 4.4+ :( 

That's the reason...

Comment: @Leukipp I suggest you that if you use window Sysytem, then create batch (*.bat) file with code `adb start-server`. And run on system start every time

Answer (score 58):

If you can use an Android 4.4+ device, then you can use Chrome Remote Debugging even on the app's internal WebView. It's a much better debugger than Weinre, but the key is using the recent Android version.

Recent Cordova builds automatically enable this kind of debugging as long as it's a debug build (it's turned off in --release builds).

Comment: Looks great - also noticed there is a phonegap build plugin available to enable this feature.

Comment: As per your comment : it's turned off in --release builds (Thats not true)

Comment: Re. this, I found [this link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/debugging-android) useful. Pertinently, use Chrome to navigate to `chrome://inspect` and make sure "Discover USB Devices" is checked. This will show up any debug-able WebViews in connected devices.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that `console.log` doesn't seem to work. You need to go through `alerts` which is really a burden.

Comment: `(it's turned off in --release builds).` this notice saved my day!

Answer (score 35):

The best for me is to attach the Chrome debugger.

To do it, run your app in a emulator or device (using $cordova emulate)

then, open Google Chrome and go to `chrome://inspect/`

You'll see a list with running apps. Your app should be there. Click on "inspect".

A new window will open with developer tools. There you can click on "console" to check for errors

Comment: Please double check your answer will work in OP's conditions. The Chrome debugger only works with Android 4.4+.

Answer (score 21):

If your app is running Cordova 3.3+ and your device is running Android 4.4+ then you can use **Chrome Remote Webview Debugging** to debug your Cordova app.

To be able to do that, you must first enable USB debugging on you phone.

Then open the "inspect devices" tab. In Chrome, go to **Settings** > **More tools** > **Inspect devices**.

If you launch your app on your device while it's connected to your computer, The Webview should appear in the devices list. Click on the "Inspect" link of your Webview and a Debug Tool for your Webview should appear.

Here is an article fully explaining how to do it: http://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-android/

Comment: This is one of the best and most complete answers of this comment section, even though it doesn't help OP because of 4.4+.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried ['GapDebug'](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/)? Its free.

It appears to integrate versions of the Safari Webkit Inspector and Chrome Dev Tools to offer an integrated debugging experience on OS X and Windows.

Comment: This is an essential tool especially for Windows users wanting to connect to step debug iPhone - I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is Visual Studio, which has [prerelease support for debugging Cordova apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771545.aspx):

> **Unified debugging experience**. Cross-platform development often
>   requires a different tool for debugging each device, emulator, or
>   simulator. Different tools mean different workflows and lost
>   productivity every time you switch devices. With Visual Studio, you
>   can use the same world-class debugging tools for all deployment
>   targets, including Windows, the Android emulator, attached Android
>   devices, iOS devices and emulators, and the Apache Ripple emulator.

Now that Microsoft has released [Visual Studio Community edition for free](http://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2013-community-vs), you can give this a try at no cost. You will need to download both Visual Studio, and [Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/prerelease-software-downloads-vs#AdditionalPageSections_8).

Comment: Since Intel's once-amazing XDK stopped support for its debugger, I've had to look for a new option. Visual Studio is the only one I've found that is all-in-one solution (IDE, debugger, plugin manager, etc.). Setup takes a while but it's very simple. I use Enterprise 2015. It builds but I'm not sure if it publishes yet (I haven't reached that point).

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, the only productive tool for real debugging in Cordova apps for Android platforms from 2.2 to 4.3 is [jshybugger](http://jshybugger.com/#!/). [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/Home.html) is an inspector, not a debugger. JsHybugger instruments your code allowing you to debug inside the android WebView.

Answer (score 5):

Just want to add that you can debug android apps using [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com). It's WAY faster then the stock android emulator.

Comment: Genymotion allows to use chrome remote debugging since it is not treated as emulator but as real device. Camera and other hardware features work as well, but some of them are paid.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Intel XDK IDE to develop and debug on emulator or on real device

I also found Visual Studio 2015 RC tools for cordova very good, with it's ripple emulator

Answer (score 4):

On Android 4.4+ w/SDK installed:

```
adb logcat chromium:D SystemWebViewClient:D \*:S
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the solution using Phonegap Build. Add the following to your config.xml to be able to inspect with Chrome Remote Webview Debugging.

First, make sure your widget tag contains xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

```
<widget 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
    xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id="me.app.id" 
    version="1.0.0">
```

Then add the following

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
     <application android:debuggable="true" />
</gap:config-file>
```

It works for me on Nexus 5, Phonegap 3.7.0.

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
```

Build the app in Phonegap Build, install the APK, connect the phone to the USB, enable USB debugging on you phone then visit chrome://inspect.

Source:
https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/learning-center/configuration/

Comment: HOLY BEJEEZUS!!!  I can FINALLY debug my apk's!!!  Thank you so much, I don't know why this isn't anywhere else more prominent.  Including these notes verbatim in the readme of my project.

Answer (score 3):

If you use phonegap build, there is an option to enable debug.

---

For local builds, you can install weinre with npm : https://npmjs.org/package/weinre

And the link to the weinre docs : http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

---

And there is something called chrome remote debugging but I don't know much about it, you can have a look at Raymond Camden's article : http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2014/1/2/Apache-Cordova-33-and-Remote-Debugging-for-Android

Docs for the chrome remote debugging : https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging
(if I understood correctly you need an android device with chrome as default browser)
Maybe the closest to your dream solution?

Comment: Thanks for the infos; I prefer to use the free cordova way ;) and I got it working now (check my answer) thanks! +1

Comment: check my edit, it seems that chrome is not far from your dream solution after all

Comment: Note that the device I'm using is runing android 2.3 while the chrome remote debugging requires Android 4.4 or higher. But thanks "QuickFix" ; I got everything working now.. see my tutorial ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can debug **Cordova Android Applications which are installed on your phone** remotely from your computer via the USB cable (you can also remotely click on the web application as if you were viewing the web application from your compueter) with "Chrome Remote Debugging". **You can also debug web application viewed in the Stock Android browser or Chrome on Android** this way.

1. Enable developer mode on your Android device (go to settings -> about phone -> tap 7x on the build number).
2. Connect your computer with your phone via USB cable.
3. Lunch Chrome on your computer and navigate to chrome://inspect and click the "Inspect" button next to the remote device which you want to debug (under the "Devices" tab). **OR** right click inside Chrome on your computer -> Inspect -> Costumize and control DevTools (3 vertical dots - top right corner of the developer tools) -> More tools -> Remote Devices -> under Devices on the left side, click on your device to which you are connected via USB -> click on the Inspect button for the application you want.
4. Then click on "Console" and you can debug JavaScript the same way, as you would on a normal web application with Chrome developer tools.

Comment: This works on my phone (android 6) but does not work on my tablet (note 8 android 4.4)

Comment: It was a problem with the android web-view. Installing crosswalk plugin allows me to make this kind of debugging on older devices (up to jelly bean)

Answer (score 2):

You can also debug with chrome your html5 apps

I create a .bat to open chrome in debug mode

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
chrome.exe "file:///C:\Users\***.html" --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

Comment: Thanks but I found the best approach is to use weinre to debug the desing with the integrated webkit browser of the device itself!

Comment: I second that, whereas ripple gives you an average idea on how it will look when you release it, which is good, sometimes there are differences comparing the emulator and real device, mainly because the emulator works with the engine of the web browser you're running on it, which is not the same in some situations as your device will work. So I usually use both, ripple to design the UI, and weinre to test behavior when something doesn't works as expected

Answer (score 2):

If you're **using Cordova 3.3 or higher** and your device is **running Android 4.4 or higher** you can use 'Remote Debugging on Android with Chrome'. Full instructions are here:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

In summary:

- Plug the device into your desktop computer using a USB cable
- Enable USB debugging on your device (on my device this is under Settings > More > Developer options > USB debugging)

***Or***, if you're using Cordova 3.3+ and don't have a physical device with 4.4, you can use an emulator that uses Android 4.4+ to run the application through the emulator, on your desktop computer.

- Run your Cordova application on the device or emulator
- In Chrome on your desktop computer, enter chrome://inspect/#devices in the address bar
- Your device/emulator will be displayed along with any other recognised devices that are connected to your computer, and under your device there will be details of the Cordova 'WebView' (basically your Cordova app), which is running on the device/emulator (the way Cordova works is that it basically creates a 'browser' window on your device/emulator, within which there is a 'WebView' which is your running HTML/JavaScript app)
- Click the 'inspect' link under the 'WebView' section where you see your device/emulator listed. This brings up the Chrome developer tools that now allow you to debug your application.
- Select the 'sources' tab of the Chrome developer tools to view JavaScript that your Cordova app on the device/emulator is currently running. You can add breakpoints in the JavaScript that allow you to debug your code.
- Also, you can use the 'console' tab to view any errors (which will be shown in red), or at the bottom of the console you'll see a '>' prompt. Here you can type in any variables or objects (e.g. DOM objects) that you want to inspect the current value of, and the value will be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

**Use Android Device Monitor**

Android Device Monitor comes packages with android sdk which you would have installed previously. In the device monitor you can see you entire device log, exceptions, messages everything. This is usefully to debug application crashes or any other such problems. To run this, go to tools/ folder inside your android sdk “/var/android-sdk-linux/tools”. Then run the following

```
chmod +x monitor
./monitor
```

If you are on windows, directly open the monitor.exe file.
There is a tab below “LogCat” where you will see all device related message. You will see all messages here including android device exceptions which are not visible chrome inspect device. Be sure to create filters using the “+” sign in logcat tab, so that you see messages only for your application.

Source: http://excellencenodejsblog.com/phonegap-debugging-your-android-application/

Comment: For Linux users, depending on your SDK installation method, it might also be found in ~/Android/Sdk/tools/monitor or just try typing `monitor`.

Answer (score 1):

I've loved weinre! How to use it:

First, put on your `index.html` (ensure `app.settings.debugUrl` is set before this):

```
  <!-- Weinre debugging -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (app.settings.debugUrl) {
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        var s = document.createElement("script")
        s.setAttribute("src", app.settings.debugUrl+"/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous")
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(s)
      }); 
    }   
  </script>
```

Then:

- install: `sudo npm install -g weinre`
- run: `weinre --boundHost -all-`
- open on browser: http://localhost:8080/client/#anonymous
- watch targets appear as you open the app

Based on http://www.broken-links.com/2013/06/28/remote-debugging-with-weinre/

Comment: Weinre isn't debugger, it allows only DOM inspections, you can't debug js and even watch console messages,

Answer (score 1):

Devices with android <=4.0.4 need to add the plugin  https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-pgb-adapt