# On Android 4.1, can we use DevTools to debug WebView content in native Android applications

Tags: cordova, webview

I m building android app with cordova .I m able to debug the app, which is running in the emulator.And also with devices which is having android 4.4 or later versions BUT not with the devices having android 4.1 version. Since there is one issue which is seen only in real device of android (version 4.1) .Can u please suggest any solution.

Comment: you can use weinre, here you have more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332853/is-there-a-real-solution-to-debug-cordova-apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper remote debugging via Chrome is only available for Android 4.4+ when using the platform WebView, so your only option with vanilla Cordova is JavaScript hacks like Weinre.

If you're interested, AppGyver's [Steroids tooling](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids) comes with Crosswalk for Android, which will let you use an up-to-date fork of Chromium instead of the platform WebView – this fixes many rendering issues and allows you to access the Chrome Inspector for debugging what happens in the Webview.

You can [run Steroids it in your Cordova project](http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/cli/usage-with-cordova/) directly without modifying any files, so check it out.

(Disclaimer: I'm a programmer for AppGyver.)