# How Open downloaded files in ios with cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova

I finished the downloading part in ios.

But for opening the download files I used file opener plugin in android, which is working well in android. But for ios file opener plugin is not working.

Can any one help me out? Thanks in advance :).

Comment: need more info on error and link to ios plugin you are using ,also iOS version.

Comment: which plugin you used. 
Try with [this one](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2)

Comment: com.phonegap.fileopener this one i have used. The following code i have used to open the downloaded files in android  window.plugins.fileOpener.open(decodeURI(entry.toURL()));

Comment: @Nirus This same piece of code is working in android(window.plugins.fileOpener.open(decodeURI(entry.toURL()))). But I am testing myapp in iphone 4s and 5s. I don't know how to debug in iphone. Is there any way to debug the code in web browser like as chrome for android.

Comment: @manukv I am testing on device, how to see the errors on device. I am new to ios.

Comment: Think you are using the plugin "markeeftb/FileOpener", and this supports android only. try this [plugin](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2)

Comment: You can use Safari to remote debug on iOS: http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html

Comment: @daserge but safari debugging is enabled for iphone 6 onwards.

Comment: @manukv here is the plugin info <plugin 
    xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    id="com.phonegap.plugins.fileopener" 
    version="0.0.3">

Comment: You can use cordova-weinre for debugging. check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332853/is-there-a-real-solution-to-debug-cordova-apps)

Comment: Thank You manukv for your help :).

Comment: @Krishna, not iPhone 6, but iOS 6 is required.

Comment: thanks your help. Now I will try to debug my app on iphone device - @daserge

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are using an old one, 
Try fileopener2

install plugin through cli

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-opener2
```

and usage is

```
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
    '/sdcard/Download/mypdf.pdf', // You can also use a Cordova-style file uri: cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Download/starwars.pdf
    'application/pdf', 
    { 
        error : function(e) { 
            console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
        },
        success : function () {
            console.log('file opened successfully');                
        }
    }
);
```

UPDATE

you can specify the MIME-type (second field) from the list of MIME types. 
These are the [list of known MIME-types](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types?view=co)

Comment: Is it necessary to pass the second argument. In my case i have dynamic data download option it may be .pdf or .doc or .png.

Comment: Im afraid you did not answer the Krishna's question