# Cordova - How to see errors and console.log in Android Emulator

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, console, emulation

I'm building an app for Android using Cordova & html,JS. And using the Android emulator from the plain SDK Manager. 
I seem to have a lot of isues with my code, but I can't figure out what.
So I need to check for errors in the console log like we do with browsers.

The only thing I've managed to do is use is the `adb -e logcat > logcat.txt` command. Yet the output file is way too convoluted for me.
And when I filter the output using
`adb -e logcat > logcat.txt io.cordova.app:D *:S`, 
the output file contains only

`--------- beginning of main
 --------- beginning of system`

What can I do about it? Is there any other way learning the errors of my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have started the emulator through Eclipse you can see the logs in Logcat.

```
Window -> Show View -> Android -> LogCat
```

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention that I'm using only the Android SDK Manager. So that is not an option for me

Comment: Check this thread whether it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332853/is-there-a-real-solution-to-debug-cordova-apps

Comment: I checked that out but it seems way to complicated for me. I've downloaded the Eclipse IDE. Is is possible to somehow import my app to it?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out my self. Now I use Eclipse(for Android) with the Android Emulator. So your answer is the correct one