# ML5 image classifiers returns exactly the same results for all images on cordova android platform

Tags: android, cordova, p5.js, tensorflow.js

I just started working with ML5 and machine learning in general. I started by creating an app that classifies images from my webcam using 'MobileNet' image classifier, I then created a my own classifier using Teachable Machine which also worked great. I created my app using cordova, and I used the browser platform as I got started and all worked great. 
However once I switched to try the app on android platform, whatever image I try to classify (whether it is taken with my phone camera, or even hard-coded to the html page) always returns the same result with the exact same confidence. But if I switch back to the browser, it works just fine again. I cant seem to find anyone else reporting this kind of problem. Does anyone have any idea what it might be?

Comment: If I have platform differences I would check for related github issues: https://github.com/ml5js/ml5-library/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+android AND https://github.com/ml5js/ml5-library/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging using Chrome Developer Tools ([by following this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30234049/6152378)), it appears the problem was that the images I was trying to classify were too large to be processed on android (error - webGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: width or height out of range).

Therefore reducing the size/quality of the images before classifying them resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I once had the same problem and it turned out that the Android version was having out-of-memory exceptions that weren't being caught or reported.

Comment: Only by using a smaller model. Also I caught and displayed error messages to diagnose my problem. (Only later did I learn how to use Chrome Developer Tools with an Android phone to see the console messages.)